# Qt unit test dependency problem

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt

Hee,

I'm kinda new to Qt and i started to add UnitTests to my Qt project. Qt demands that i put my unit tests in another project, so i did.
But now i have dependent source files in my first project. I made my 'main project' a dependency of my 'test project'.
I cannot seem to include any of the '.h' files from my 'main project'. The unit test them self run properly as long as i do not use classes from my 'main project'.

I looked into the Qt documentation, but i cannot find the solution for my problem. Am i missing something?

Comment: Qt doesn't require that your unit tests be in another project.

Comment: @Bill: The only way i could find how to add Unit tests to Qt creator is by adding another project. Can you then explain or post a link to a proper tutorial how to set that up?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Qt creator, and now that I think about it more, I do have a separate .pro file for my unit tests.  (I confused project with directory... my bad!)  My standard approach is relative paths.  If all my unit test files are in a subdirectory called "unitTests", then I use `#include "../MyHeader.h"` to pull in the necessary headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to include your dependencies to .pro file of your test project?

```
HEADERS += ../MyHeader.h
SOURCES += ../MyHeader.cpp \
      tst_myUnitTestName.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the path of your main program in the includes (in the testProject.pro file)

> INCLUDEPATH += .. .

(or just add the path to the project itself)

if you do this, you will then need to change your includes (in the .cpp files) from "" to <>

> #include < MyHeader.h >

Adding the headers to the .pro file will mostly allow you to have easy access to the file itself if you're using QtCreator (and qmake will complain if it doesn't find the files), but it will not solve the actual dependencies within each .cpp file.